# IF statement and For

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

I'm a very, very n00b developper learning Python at university (I started a few weeks ago really) and I'm on my first assignment. Everything's going well, except one thing and i just can't figure it out. Or rather, I know what the problem is, but I can't find the solution. In short, I need to ask the user to input a number, and if number is 0, then the programs shows a message and stops there. Otherwise, it goes on with asking more info and uses For loops. My question is: How do I insert lines that are not part of the IF (user has entered 0) but also not part of any For loops (i don't want these lines repeated). I'm not sure if that makes any sense.

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrqYE.png)

basically i want the last print to be shown if the user has entered more than 0 in the beginning, but not be shown if the user has entered 0. I'm not showing the actual code, since it's a uni assignment, but the screenshot shows exactly the issue I'm having with the real code :) Thanks for your help!! (also, sorry that it's actually a link, because i don't have enough points yet to embed the image).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one is pretty easy. Im not that great at python yet but i just tested it and it works as intended.

```
def isZero(val):
    if val==0:
        print('bye')
        quit()      

title = int(input('enter a number'))
ZeroCheck = isZero(title)
while title>0:
    title = int(input('enter a number'))
    isZero(title)
```

Comment: thank you so much, i figured it was something really small but i couldn't fix it. That's exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Comment: @Vildred if it works and solves you rissue make sure to mark as answered